# Setting/Getting foreign key in Hibernate & Java

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, foreign-keys

Pretty sure this is trivial but unable to find a straight forward answer. I have Dept/Emp tables. Where dept_id in the emp table is a foreign key. It is a classical one-to-many relationship. In a web application, on the new employee page the dept is a Select control listing available depts. When a user submits a page, I have Emp details and the dept id. But I can't set the Dept id on the Emp class because there is not setter or getter to Dept id in the Emp class!

What is the best option to handle this?

I am using Struts2 2.1.8/hibernate 3.x/tomcat 6.0.26/MySQL 5.5.x

Comment: Do you JPA with Hibernate or only Hibernate?

Comment: looking at the answers with much appreciation, I need to clarify what I am looking for. On a submit of a new Employee, my action receives the request object populated with users' input including dept id. So I proceed to create the employee class and use the setters to add users' input. But the Hibernate Emp class doesn't have a setter for Dept id because it's a foreign key. What I could do is look up the Dept and assign dept to Emp. But that seems too much for a simple setDeptId(value)!

Answer (score 0):

you should have set of Emp in Dept. And if one emp can exist in one dept than there will be many-to-one of dept in emp, but if one emp can exist more than one dept than you will be needed set of Dept in Emp.

Please refer how to define [collection mapping in hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html)?

Comment: Thanks but not really what i was asking. Please see my comment to @Pau-Kiat.

Comment: you have one-to-many relationship between Dept and Emp. If I am not wrong, your relationship would be like one Dept has more than one Emp. So, you have set<Emp> in Dept. If you have relation like this than you can make it bidirectional and you can put many-to-one of Dept in Emp. So, when you get deptId, you just simply make object of Dept and set deptId in that object. Now, set that Dept object in Emp and finally save your Emp object. This will work if you took set<Emp> not List<Emp>. Because in we need to maintain position.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I am doing now. Being a traditional developer, I was hoping there would be a more direct way where i don't create a dept object and I would just set det_id on the emp object (i.e. emp.setDeptId(value))

Answer (score 0):

You can do in Service Layer

```
service.add(employee, id);
```

in `Service.add(Employee employee, String id)`

```
public void add(Employee employee, String id) {
    Department department = session.get(Department.class, id);
    employee.setDepartment(department);
    session.persist(employee);
}
```

But you need have setter in `Employee` class to set employee's `Department`

Comment: Thanks but that is not my question (my fault), i am trying to set the dept id in employee. For example:<code>employee e; ... e.setDeptId(value);</code>

Answer (score 0):

You have two Dept, the old one to which the Emp belonged before, and the new one, which the user had chosen where the Emp belongs now. Each of the two Dept have a set with all the employes belonging to them.

In one transaction you remove Emp from the set of employes in the old Dept, you add it to the set of employes in the new Dept and the update these two Dept with session.update(Dept). If you do not have the cascade for the employes, you have to update the Emp, too.

This looks more complicated, but in this way the employes sets in both Dept are still correct, and at the database side this should result in only one SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks but not really what i was asking. Please see my comment to @Pau-Kiat.

Comment: When updating the new Dept, hibernate should automatically set the deptId in the employes belonging to this Dept.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered from this question is that you might not have configured your bean correctly. You will have to define the ORM mapping in your beans like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EmployeeMaster")
public class empBean {

@Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "departmentFkId", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Long departmentFkId;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "departmentFkId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private DepartmentMasterBean department;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public DepartmentMasterBean getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(DepartmentMasterBean department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public Long getDepartmentFkId() {
    return departmentFkId;
}

public void setDepartmentFkId(Long departmentFkId) {
    this.departmentFkId = departmentFkId;
}
}
```

Now you can set the department details(`empBean.setDepartmentFkId`) and hibernate will handle the rest of the saving via the session(`session.saveOrUpdate(empBean)`).